# How to setup inspection for Spring JPA?

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I wrote simple Spring JPA repository with a method, annotated with `@Query`. Unfortunately, IntelliJ inspection swears table name not found:

[image]

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

Available autofixes:

[image]

Comment: Try alt+enter on the red waved term

Comment: Only general options available, like disable inspection.

Comment: You must configure a datasource/database, and intellij will then offer you the ability to link the code you're looking at to the configured datasource. I think this only works in Ultimate. Hi Dims :)

Comment: @EngineerDollery how can datasource link help? I found experimentally, that names like `Customer` is not the actual names of tables, but names of classes?

Comment: Because Intellij uses the assigned datasources to actually look in the database to confirm that your code/queries are correct and to offer code-completion. It'll help with jpa annotations on entities too.. It's smart like that. You can also open consoles and perform ad-hoc queries and DDL, with intellisense and completion.

Comment: Suppose I have `@Table(name = "CLIENT") public class Customer`. So, the name of entity is `Client` in datasource and `Customer` in `@Query`. So, knowing datasource can only confuse intellisense.

Comment: I believe @EngineerDollery 's suggestion should work. I'd expect IJ to have an annotation processing module which would correctly link table names with entities.

Comment: @Dims -- Morfic is correct. IJ works fine in this scenario -- nothing gets confused. Like I said, it's smart -- hence the name. Think of it like an AI -- I do -- it's more like one than not.